# extracting the file and invoice from SAP

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have below code.
In first loop the excel file is extracted from the SAP - loop with variable a.

In the second loop (loop with variable k) the invoice is extracted from SAP (takes the order number from earlier extracted excel file).
The number of the order is taken from the excel file and paste to order in SAP.
Sometimes it happens, that order is either not taken from excel or not paste in SAP and the field for the order is empty.
This situation try to generates all the orders for the Controlling Area, which is very time-consuming (in fact it lasts hours).

I tried to add this line of code before the paste to the order, but of no result

`Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")`

Have you met this in your coding and could help with this?

extracting the excel file from SAP

```
Sub invoice_extr()

'##########################
'zapisuje pliki xlsx ordery
'##########################


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SheetSrc = "Input data"

    On Error Resume Next
    
    
    If Not IsObject(SAPApplication) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set SAPApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = SAPApplication.Children(0)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Please, open SAP!")

            Exit Sub
        Else

        End If
    End If

    If Not IsObject(session) Then
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
 
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") / 1.5)
    
    Dim a As Double
    Dim last_row As Double
    
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Range("b2:c" & last_row).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    
    Dim path As String
    path = Cells(2, 6)
    
    For a = 2 To last_row
    
'###########################################################
'####SPRAWDZA CZY JEST JUZ PLIK XLSX O TAKIEJ NAZWIE########
'###########################################################
    
    Dim objFSO_november1 As Object
Dim objFolder_november1 As Object
Dim objFile_november1 As Object
Dim objFile1_november1 As Object
Dim aa_november1 As Integer


Dim bb_november1 As Integer

Set objFSO_november1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder_november1 = objFSO_november1.GetFolder(path)

bb_november1 = 0
For Each objFile1_november1 In objFolder_november1.Files

bb_november1 = bb_november1 + 1

Next objFile1_november1

Dim myArray_november1() As Variant
ReDim Preserve myArray_november1(bb_november1, 1)
aa_november1 = 0

For Each objFile_november1 In objFolder_november1.Files

myArray_november1(aa_november1, 1) = objFile_november1.name

aa_november1 = aa_november1 + 1
Next objFile_november1

Dim aa As Double

Dim zz As Double
zz = 0
For aa = 0 To aa_november1 - 1
Dim how_many As Double
how_many = Len(Cells(a, 1))
'MsgBox (Cells(a, 1))
'MsgBox (Left(myArray_november1(aa, 1), how_many))
'MsgBox (aa)
If (Cells(a, 1) * 1) = (Left(myArray_november1(aa, 1), how_many) * 1) Then
Cells(a, 2) = "Done"
zz = zz + 1
'MsgBox (zz)
End If
If zz <> 0 Then
GoTo line1
End If
Next aa
Erase myArray_november1

If zz <> 0 Then
GoTo line1
End If



    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/Ns_alr_87013019"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txt$6-KOKRS").Text = Cells(a, 4)
Workbooks("Saving_invoice.xlsm").Activate
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").Text = Cells(a, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
'On Error GoTo line1
On Error Resume Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont[2]/shell").hierarchyHeaderWidth = 453
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[62,8]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[62,8]").caretPosition = 9
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,2]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,2]").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 2
'################################################################
'#############WYBIERA LAYOUT /MACRO##############################
'################################################################
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[33]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = -1
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "VARIANT"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&FILTER"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").Text = "/MACRO"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").clickCurrentCell
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").currentCellColumn = "BELNR"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectedRows = "0"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cmbG_LISTBOX").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cmbG_LISTBOX").Key = "31"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = path
Dim name As String
name = Cells(a, 1) & ".xlsx"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = name
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
'line1:
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")


 If Not Dir(path & name, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
 Dim wB1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

  With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set wB1 = Workbooks.Open(path & name)
    Set ws1 = wB.Sheets(1)
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")
    Workbooks(name).Activate

    Workbooks(name).Close

    Cells(a, 2) = "Done"
    
    Else
    
    Cells(a, 2) = "Please, check the order!"
    
 End If



'Dim wB1 As Workbook
'Dim ws1 As Worksheet
'
'  With Application
'        .DisplayAlerts = False
'        .EnableEvents = False
'        .ScreenUpdating = False
'    End With
'
'    Set wB1 = Workbooks.Open(path & name)
'    Set ws1 = wB.Sheets(1)
'
'    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")


'Workbooks(name).Activate
'
'Workbooks(name).Close
'
'Cells(a, 2) = "Checked"

line1:
Erase myArray_november1
Next a

Call invoice_extr_2

End Sub
```

extracting the invoice from SAP

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SheetSrc = "Input data"

    On Error Resume Next
    
    
    If Not IsObject(SAPApplication) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set SAPApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = SAPApplication.Children(0)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Please, open SAP!")

            Exit Sub
        Else

        End If
    End If

    If Not IsObject(session) Then
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
 
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") / 1.5)


'####################################
'otwiera ordery i zapisuje faktury
'####################################

Workbooks("Saving_invoice.xlsm").Activate

Dim path As String

path = Cells(2, 6).Value

Dim last_row As Double

last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Double
For i = 2 To last_row

Dim name2 As String
name2 = Cells(i, 1) & ".xlsx"

Dim wB2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

If Not Dir(path & name2, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then

  With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set wB2 = Workbooks.Open(path & name2)
    'Set ws2 = wB.Sheets(1)
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")


Workbooks(name2).Activate
Else
GoTo line999999999
End If

Dim last_column As Integer

last_column = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'MsgBox (last_column)

Dim nr_kolumny As Long
nr_kolumny = Cells.Find(What:="Ref Document Number", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column

If Cells(1, last_column) = "action" Then
Dim ostatnia_kolumna As Integer
ostatnia_kolumna = Cells.Find(What:="action", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
Else
ostatnia_kolumna = last_column + 1
End If

If Cells(1, last_column) = "action" Then
GoTo line2
Else
    Cells(1, last_column + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "action"
End If
line2:
    
Dim k As Double
Dim last_row_document



last_row_document = Cells(Rows.Count, nr_kolumny).End(xlUp).Row - 2
For k = 2 To last_row_document
If Cells(k, ostatnia_kolumna) <> "Checked" Then
Workbooks("Saving_invoice").Activate
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/Ns_alr_87013019"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txt$6-KOKRS").Text = Cells(i, 4)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").Text = Cells(i, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
On Error Resume Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont[2]/shell").hierarchyHeaderWidth = 453
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[62,8]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[62,8]").caretPosition = 9
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,2]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,2]").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 2
'#####################################################
'##############WYBIERA LAYOUT /MACRO##################
'#####################################################
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[33]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = -1
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectColumn "VARIANT"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&FILTER"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").Text = "/MACRO"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").clickCurrentCell
'######################################################
'############TUTAJ FILTROWANIE PO DOKUMENCIE###########
'######################################################
Workbooks(name2).Activate
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").setCurrentCell -1, "REFBN"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectColumn "REFBN"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[29]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").Text = Cells(k, nr_kolumny)
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").currentCellColumn = "REFBN"
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectedRows = "0"
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell

'###########################################################
'####SPRAWDZA CZY JEST JUZ PLIK O TAKIEJ NAZWIE#############
'###########################################################
Dim objFSO_november As Object
Dim objFolder_november As Object
Dim objFile_november As Object
Dim objFile1_november As Object
Dim aa_november As Integer


Dim bb_november As Integer

Set objFSO_november = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder_november = objFSO_november.GetFolder(path)

bb_november = 0
For Each objFile1_november In objFolder_november.Files

bb_november = bb_november + 1

Next objFile1_november

Dim myArray_november() As Variant
ReDim Preserve myArray_november(bb_november, 1)
aa_november = 0

For Each objFile_november In objFolder_november.Files

myArray_november(aa_november, 1) = objFile_november.name

aa_november = aa_november + 1
Next objFile_november

Dim z As Double
Dim how_digits As Double
how_digits = Len(Cells(k, nr_kolumny))
Dim s As Double

s = 0

For z = 0 To aa_november
If Left(myArray_november(z, 1), how_digits) = Cells(k, nr_kolumny) Then
s = s + 1
End If
Next z

Erase myArray_november

Dim h As Double
Dim o As Double

o = 0
For h = 2 To k
If Cells(h, nr_kolumny) = Cells(k, nr_kolumny) Then
o = o + 1
End If
Next h

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectedRows = o - 1 'tutaj nr linii po filtrowaniu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell
session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").pressContextButton "%GOS_TOOLBOX"
session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "%GOS_VIEW_ATTA"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_FILTER"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&FILTER"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/subSUB_DYN0500:SAPLSKBH:0600/cntlCONTAINER1_FILT/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 2
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/subSUB_DYN0500:SAPLSKBH:0600/cntlCONTAINER1_FILT/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "2"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/subSUB_DYN0500:SAPLSKBH:0600/btnAPP_WL_SING").press
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/subSUB_DYN0500:SAPLSKBH:0600/btn600_BUTTON").press
session.findById("wnd[3]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").Text = "Invoice"
session.findById("wnd[3]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_FREESEL:SAPLSSEL:1105/ctxt%%DYN001-LOW").caretPosition = 7
session.findById("wnd[3]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "BITM_DESCR"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_0100/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarButton "%ATTA_EXPORT"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = path
If s = 0 Then
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(k, nr_kolumny).Value & ".PDF"
Else
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(k, nr_kolumny).Value & "-" & s + 1 & ".PDF"
End If
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 5
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")
Workbooks(name2).Activate
Cells(k, ostatnia_kolumna) = "Checked"
Workbooks(name2).Save
End If


Next k
Workbooks("Saving_invoice").Activate
Cells(i, 3) = "Checked"

Workbooks("Saving_invoice.xlsm").Save

Workbooks(name2).Save
Workbooks(name2).Close

line999999999:

Next i

Workbooks("Saving_invoice.xlsm").Activate
If Cells(1, 11) = "action" Then
Columns("K:K").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End If
Cells(1, 1).Activate
Workbooks("Saving_invoice.xlsm").Save

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove your `On Error Resume Next` statement and tell us exactly what happens. As it stands you’re completely ignoring any error that might happen during or after your SAP script

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the ```On Error Resume Next```. Now I have this error refers to extracted from SAP excel file - File in Use nameofthefile.xlsx is locked for editing by me. When I extract from SAP the file is saved in the location and it's open automatically. It happens not for all the files, only for some and sometimes.

Comment: How can I open this file only for read using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Well **Application.Wait** "The time at which you want the macro to resume, in Microsoft Excel date format." So it only pauses your VBA code but not "lets wait till some lines finishes work and we will continue" not sure how to write correctly :D bad in English. But hope you understood.

I suggest you to use Immediate window, and check everything is in place(values) with Debug.Print "My value: " & variable, also VBA is tricky and trying to make people less code while it automatically converts string, int and other stuff which is not declared or misspelled. So make on top "**Option Explicit**", then declare everything what is not declared.

And delete "**On Error Resume Next**", cause you cant see first error.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed ```On Error Resume Next```, have the other error message. I don't know if my previous answer is visible, so I'll copy it here as well.                                          Thanks, I've removed the On Error Resume Next. Now I have this error refers to extracted from SAP excel file - File in Use nameofthefile.xlsx is locked for editing by me. When I extract from SAP the file is saved in the location and it's open automatically. It happens not for all the files, only for some and sometimes. How can I open this file only for read using VBA?

Comment: @Kamil Workbooks.Open FilePathString, UpdateLinks(True / False), ReadOnly(True / False)